# Make sure data lands in correct tabe column in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a model:

```
class UserReport(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_user))
    period = models.ForeignKey(Period, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True,
    null=True)
    points = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

My goal is to make a table: Periods on top of the table, then each row is for user and points corresponding to period.

```
_______________________________
Periods  | 1    |2    |3    
_________________________________
user 1    | 74   | 84  | 84  
user 2    | 74   |     | 84  
user 3    |      | 84  | 84
```

The problem: there might me no data entry for every period.

How do I make sure, that points goes into right place (column)?

On top of that, periods might start form any number.

What I did try:
in views i have:

```
        users_data.append(UserReport.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('period'))
```

then in template:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>User</th>

        {% for period in periods  %}
          <th>{{period}}</th>
        {% endfor %}
        
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
{% for user in users_data  %}  
      <tr>          
          <td>{{user.0.user}}</td>

<!-- Some smart logic should go here. Tis is my attempt which does not work -->
          {% for period in periods  %}
            {% for entry in user   %}
              {% if period == entry.period %}
                <td>{{entry.period}}-{{entry.points}}</td>
                
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
       
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
     
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I could probably achieve this making a lists in views.py, but I think it is representation logic and should go to template.

Comment: i think, you need to prepare all your data in views and don't try to do any calculations in templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this built-in filter [default_if_none](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none), if the value is None, uses the given default, also there is another similar filter called `default`, which  works on empty string('') but not `None`

```
# if value is None -> use empty space
{{ value|default_if_none:"" }}

# if value is None -> use hyphen
{{ value|default_if_none:"-" }}
```